# filtering backbone collection on return 1 results

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone.js-collections

I am trying to filter a backbone collection to return only models that match a couple of attributes, I am wanting to return only models that have an owner_id that is null, and a user_id that is equal to "1".  Here is my code,

```
myFilter: function( owner_id, user_id) {
    console.log(owner_id, user_id);
    var filtered = this.filter(function(user) {
        return user.get("owner_id") === owner_id && user.get("user_id") === user_id});
    return new App.Collections.MyClients(filtered);
}
```

I know there are 2 matching records in my collection, but I only ever get the first returned, why is this?

The collection data looks like this,

```
id  name        information     type     user_id    owner_id
18  Client 1                    client       1         NULL
19  Client 2                    client       1         32
20  Client 3                    client       1         NULL
```

The user_id gets return as a string

Comment: Can you post the collection data?

Comment: see edit. I have what the database rows look like

Comment: Could you try changing the strict equality operator (===) to a normal equality operator (==)? I'm thinking that the `NULL` value in the `owner_id` column might not be the correct type when you're using it in your code.

Comment: That randomly returns no results, I wondered if was because I was sending null as the first param of the myFilter function?

Comment: Ok I so I coded in that owner_id should be null and taken it out of the parameters now i am getting model return but only the first model that matches

Comment: That's really strange. I can't see anything obviously wrong with your code -- hopefully someone else with a bit more knowledge than me can help you out.

Comment: What values are coming out of your calls to `get`?

Comment: Hi @Udders. Can you show me the code for your Client model?

Comment: Hi folks, sorry for the delay in replying, it turned out it was an error in the API.

Answer (score 0):

From looking at the collection data you posted the most obvious answer seems to be that your `MyClient` model has an `idAttribute` of `user_id`.

A Backbone Collection cannot contain duplicated models, duplicated in this case meaning models with the same `idAttribute`.

Assuming an `idAttribute` of `user_id`, when you call:

`return new App.Collections.MyClients(filtered);`

your `MyClients` collection will only contain the first model with a `user_id` of 1, despite your `filtered` object containing multiple models with a `user_id` of 1.

From the `set` method in the backbone annotated source code:

```
// If a duplicate is found, prevent it from being added and optionally merge it into the existing model.
if (existing = this.get(id)) {
  if (remove) modelMap[existing.cid] = true;
    if (merge) {
      attrs = attrs === model ? model.attributes : attrs;
      if (options.parse) attrs = existing.parse(attrs, options);
      existing.set(attrs, options);
      if (sortable && !sort && existing.hasChanged(sortAttr)) sort = true;
    }
    models[i] = existing;
  }
}
```